# Can I store tif files in a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, import, raster, tiff

I have a folder of 17 images (as tif files) that I want to import into R. First, what is an efficient way to import multiple tif files? I have seen a lot of methods that work for csv files, but not tif files. Second, is it possible to store these multi-band tif files in a dataframe? Later, I am going to be looping a random forest classifier on them to assess change over time (each image is the same location at a different year), so I would like to have the images organized/easily accessible.

Comment: This should be possible with the imagemagick package, among others:  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/vignettes/intro.html#read_and_write

Comment: If these are spatial data, use `raster::stack`